# Removing elements from a stack without using peek()

Tags: java, stack

I have a stack `s` of `Student` objects and a `Student` object `e`.
How can I remove all elements of the stack above the topmost occurrence of `e` without using the `s.peek()` method?

Comment: The peek method never removes elements from the stack, though - you'd always just get the first element.  I'd say that "not using peek" is a red herring.

Comment: Why do you not want to use peek.

Comment: @Makato using peek allows for a more elegant solution: `while(s.peek() != null && !e.equals(s.peek()) { s.pop(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pop until you encounter `e`, then push `e` again.

```
Student top = null;
while(!s.isEmpty() && !e.equals(top)){
    top = s.pop();
}
if(e.equals(top)) {
    s.push(top);
} else {
    // e was not on the stack
}
```

Comment: This throws an exception if the stack `s` was initially empty.

Comment: It will too if `e` is not on the stack, I'll correct the solution

Comment: Now the algorithm doesn't solve the problem. Try changing `if(top != null)` to `if(top == e)`

Answer (score 0):

Pop the top element, and if the popped element turns out to be 'e', push it back on the stack. Else, pop stack again.